# Add new artboard with Sketch Plugin

Tags: cocoa

I'm trying to build my first Sketch Plugin that starts by adding a new Artboard to the page. Sketch plugins use [JSTalk](http://jstalk.org/), and in the [Bohemian Coding documentation](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/developer/03-reference/MSArtboardGroup.html) it states that Artboards are a type of layer, so one would think you could use `addLayerOfType` to insert a new artboard.

This is what I'm doing to try and create a new Artboard, using the JS Syntax:

```
var page = doc.currentPage()
var artboard = page.addLayerOfType("artboard")
```

However if I `log()` the output of `artboard` I get `(null)`. I've also tried it with Cocoa syntax:

```
var page = [doc currentPage]
var artboard = [page addLayerOfType:"artboard"]
```

No luck. Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Referencing the MSPage documentation](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/developer/03-reference/MSPage.html), it look like you need to use the `addLayer` method.

> ### `artboards`
>
> Returns a readonly array of all artboards on the page. If you want to
>   add a new artboard to a page, use the `addLayer` method.
>
> ### `addLayer`
>
> Adds an MSLayer to the page. For example, if you want to add an
>   800x600 artboard to the current page, you'd do this:
>
> ```
> var artboard = [MSArtboardGroup new]
> var frame = [artboard frame]
> [frame setX:0]
> [frame setY:0]
> [frame setWidth:800]
> [frame setHeight:600]
> [[doc currentPage] addLayer:artboard]
> ```

Comment: Ha! I guess reading the docs pays off. Kudos to you, my friend. Will award bounty in 2 hours (when allowed).

Comment: No worries. Sometimes you just need someone to point you in the right direction. The SO community has done that for me on a number of occasions. Glad I could help.